# MySQL: Calculate average post for every hour in each day

Tags: mysql

I trying to calculate the average post made for every hour for each day and I have to do this for 113 months. Inside the Post table have this attribute timePosted, DatePosted and Text. I also need to join two table post and thread because I only want to get category id number 3.

So far this is query that I have done.

```
select datePost as daytime,
  HOUR(timePost) as thehour, 
  count(TEXT) as thecount
  from post, thread
  where date(post.datePost) BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'
  and post.threadID = thread.threadID 
  and thread.CatID = 3
  group by datePost, thehour
```

The above subquery return me this:

```
daytime       thehour    thecount
'2010-05-01', '0',       '3'
'2010-05-01', '1',       '16'
'2010-05-01', '2',       '2'
'2010-05-01', '4',       '1'
'2010-05-01', '7',       '1'
```

I try to do the avg but the issue is that it return me the same number as thecount. Example thecount is 3 then the Avg return me 3.00000

So I trying to get this outcome:

```
daytime       thehour    thecount      Avg
'2010-05-01', '0',       '3'           #
'2010-05-01', '1',       '16'          #
'2010-05-01', '2',       '2'           #
'2010-05-01', '4',       '1'           #
'2010-05-01', '7',       '1'           #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just group by whatever you need to split by

```
select month(timePost), day(timePost), hour(timePost),avg(the_count)
from
(
  select datePost as the_day,
  timePost, 
  count(TEXT) as the_count
  from post, thread
  where post.datePost = '2010-05-03'
  and post.threadID = thread.threadID 
  and thread.CatID = 3
  group by the_day,the_hour
) s
group by 1,2,3
```

to get day of week as text, use

```
case dayofweek(date) when 1 then 'sunday' when 2 then 'monday' .... end as dayofweek
```

for the extra percent do

```
select datePost as daytime,
  HOUR(timePost) as thehour, 
  count(TEXT) as thecount,
  count(TEXT)/thecount_daily as percent_this_hour
  from post 
  inner join  thread on  post.threadID = thread.threadID 
  inner join (  select datePost as daytime_daily,
                count(TEXT) as thecount_daily
              from post inner join thread on post.threadID = thread.threadID
              where date(post.datePost) BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'
              and thread.CatID = 3
              group by datePost)daily on daily.daytime_daily=datepost



  where date(post.datePost) BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'

  and thread.CatID = 3
  group by datePost, thehour
```

for average per hour in that timeframe,

```
select datePost as daytime,
  HOUR(timePost) as thehour, 
  count(TEXT) as thecount,
  hourly_average
  from post 
  inner join  thread on  post.threadID = thread.threadID 
  inner join (  select hour(timepost) as daytime_daily,
                count(TEXT)/count(distinct datePost) as hourly_average
              from post inner join thread on post.threadID = thread.threadID
              where date(post.datePost) BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'
              and thread.CatID = 3
              group by datePost)daily on daily.daytime_daily=hour(timepost)



  where date(post.datePost) BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'

  and thread.CatID = 3
  group by datePost, thehour
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry I don't get what you mean by split by?

Comment: by month, day, hour. you are basically 'splitting' the grouped rows into these smaller groups

Comment: I made some changes above query "where post.datePost BETWEEN '2010-05-01' AND '2010-05-31'" and I have some issue with the avg function. I updated the issue above. Thanks

Comment: you are doing average of 1 value, thecount, returning sum of values/count of values, in your case the_count/1. WHat are you trying to avg?

also, change post.datepost between... to date(post.datepost) between. Otherwise, you will lose the last day in the interval, due to your dates being converted to datetime in the format '2010-05-31  00:00:00'

Comment: also please edit your first query to the current form, currently the query and putput do not have the same columns.

Comment: I try to do the avg like this AvgofPostPerHour = total Post made that hour (i.e. 00 - 01) / total post in one day (2010-05-01). Example date:2010-05-01 has total post of 117 and post made between 00 - 01 hour is 3 so I need to calculate the avg post per hour 3/117= 0.02

Comment: that is a percent, not average. Average is sum of all hours/number of hours. Added query

Comment: you can also use the function month(date) to avoid the between. Where month(datepost)=5

Comment: Sorry AdrianBR my bad. How do I find the average number of posts created in that hour slot per day?

Comment: added average. Please accept answer if it was what you needed :)

Comment: because you have no values. Change 'count(TEXT) as thecount' to 'if(count(TEXT)>0, count(text), 0) as thecount' to replace null non-values with 0 value

Comment: Thanks for ur help. When I run the query(Avg) there is some missing hour example like 0,1,2,4,7,..., 23 and missing hour like 3, 5 and 6.

Comment: the avg query is calculating avg hour or avg post per hour because I looking how to calculate the avg post?

Comment: avg posts per distinct hour for the month. in that example, for the month of may, at hour 01 of any day you have an average of x posts, at hour 2, you have y posts etc..

Comment: There something i not sure from % query and Avg query some record not tally for example in % query have the time slot 22 but it not appear Avg time slot 22?

Comment: change the inner joins to left joins when you are joining the subquery, IE inner join (  select hour(timepost) to left join (  select hour(timepost)